# Form: Manually trigger valueChange

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I'm creating a form with FormBuilder. When one of my FormControl is update I want to call another function, so I'm using `valueChanges` for that. But the thing is I want to trigger it when I initialize it. I saw that `setValue` should do the stuff but i doesn't look like working for me, or I'm just too bad.

HTML:

```html
<div class="col form-group">
  <label for="stringArray">My label</label>
  <select id="stringArray" class="form-control" *ngIf="stringArray$ | async as stringArray" formControlName="mySelect">
    <option *ngFor="let val of stringArray" [value]="val">{{ val }}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

TS

```js
public myForm: FormGroup;
public stringArray$: Observable<string[]> = null;

constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.initForm();

  this.stringArray$ = this.myForm.get('mySelect').valueChanges.pipe(
    switchMap(value => {
      return this.doSomething(value);
    })
  );
  this.myForm.get('mySelect').setValue('tmp', { emitEvent: true });
}

initForm() {
  this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    mySelect: ['', Validator.required]
  })
}

doSomething(value): Observable<string[]> {
  console.log(value);
  return of(['toto', 'tata', 'tutu', 'tmp'])
}
```

I don't have any errors, it's just that my select don't appear because `stringArray$` is `null`.

I hope my exemple is clear enougth. Thank you for your help !

Comment: what do you expecting to happen?

Comment: `this.myForm.group`?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale I was expecting my `stringArray$` to be triggered when the `setValue` is resolve.

Comment: I think you want `this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group etc.` like https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xmbham

Comment: @AndrewAllen Yes sorry, it's my bad, I didnt write it well in the exemple, I will fix it. Sorry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Great use case for the `startWith` rxjs operator! This a pattern I have a lot in my code when using `valueChange`

Here is what I personally always do.

```js
import { startWith } from 'rxjs/operators';

this.stringArray$ = this.myForm.get('mySelect')
.valueChanges.pipe(
    startWith(this.myForm.value),
    switchMap(value => {
      return this.doSomething(value);
    })
  );
```

See my [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-start-with-forms?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for an example

See documentation on the `startWith` operator [here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/startwith.html)